# Opening coverslip package

Tags: microscopy, materials

I feel pretty silly for asking this but I don't want to damage these coverslips.

I just ordered a 100ct box of coverslips and see no way to open them without destroying the container they are in. How are these little boxes typically opened? It seems smooth and sealed on all sides.

[image: coverslips]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the container from the side, it's probably a situation like this:

[image]

There *might* be some clear plastic wrap around the entire thing as well that you would need to cut/break.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using a knife to pry it open, turns out my fingernails weren't enough was all.

Comment: @Dilo You're welcome! Often times I can grasp both ends with just my fingers and pull them apart but it depends on how tight the fit is.

Comment: @Diio Thanks! I know how the package was built, but it just won't budge. I think it formed some kind of a vacuum. Pushing the cap up with a knife equally on all sides opened it, and subsequent opening is much, much easier.

Comment: Thanks for this posting. I was getting worried about my sanity. I pressed a knife edge hard on one of the sides, effectively cutting some plastic off. After that it opened w/o any trouble.

Comment: @peterd You're very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Basically the same answer, just explained differently... The top lifts off.  There is a tiny lip around the bottom edge (all four sides opposite the label). It's just a matter of getting a grip well enough to slide the top and bottom apart. (See diagram in last post, just imagine it vertically)

Thank you to the previous poster.